# image animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have to repeat the image sequence I am using with Thread and AnimationDrawable but it is not working continuously. I don't want to stop this animation until next activity is started through button click event.

Here is my java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);{

final ImageView splashImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.heartFunction);
     splashImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slide_right);
  splashAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) splashImage.getBackground();
}




public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if ( isFocused ) {
        //isFocused = false;

        splashAnimation.start();
        var=false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

slide_right.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored0" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored4" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored6" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored7" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored8" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored9" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored10" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored11" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored12" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartcolored13" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: please edit your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your animation to contiuously run then you need to set `android:oneshot="false"`

You were saying before to only run through once.

If you want an animation to run until you click the screen to go to the next activity. Start the animation when the onWindowFocusChanged function

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    splashanimation.start();
}
```

Then use an onTouchEvent to catch the touch, start a new activity and finish the old activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Anim.this, Main.class);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
     }
return true;
}
```

Hope this helps, your question is very hard to read/understand.