# Creating a custom progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

i want to create a progress bar like this.

[image: img]

i know how to create ring like progress bars. please help me....

thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best options I've found to create a circle progress bar are these libraries which you can find on Github:

https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton

Comment: i ve looked 4 this library. i want to create like one which i mentioned

Comment: your answer also seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can make an animation with pictures and use it intead of animation such as animation.

Comment: i didnt get u can u give any reference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335108/image-animation-in-android